# Finding sign of unsolvable eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following system of differential equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\ 
y'
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-a & b\\ 
 r&-(b+c)) 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I need to plot the phase portrait. I can't seem to do so because the constant matrix $A$ (which consists of constants $a$, $b$, $c$, $r$) doesn't allow you to calculate any rational eigenvalues. Is there any way to at least estimate the sign of the eigenvalues here, and to estimate something about the eigenvectors so that I can do a phase portrait?

Comment: "doesn't allow you to calculate any rational eigen values": what ??

Comment: If there are no constraints on the parameters, you just have a general $2\times2$ matrix.

Comment: Yes, but you can't find an expression for the eigen values of constant matrix A in terms of the parameters (a,b,c,r). Which is why im trying to at least figure out if I can at least find the signs of the eig values.

Comment: "but you can't find an expression for the eigen values of constant matrix A in terms of the parameters": what ???

Comment: Hint: quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The characteristic equation of

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

is the quadratic

$$\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0,$$ also written

$$\lambda^2-\text{tr}(A)\lambda+\det(A)=0.$$

Using the Vieta's formulas, if $\det(A)$ is positive, the roots have the same sign, which is the same as that of $\text{tr}(A)$.

---

Once you have the Eigenvalues,

$$\begin{pmatrix}b\\\lambda-a\end{pmatrix}$$

is an Eigenvector.